# Getting results plus no file or directory with docker run command

Tags: docker, centos

When I run a command against a docker image such as `docker run ubuntu cat /etc/*release*` I get the following result. Why do I get the "No such file or directory" along with the results? I am running docker CE version 19.03.5 on CentOS 8. Thank you.

```
cat: /etc/centos-release: No such file or directory
cat: /etc/centos-release-upstream: No such file or directory
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
cat: /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory
cat: /etc/system-release: No such file or directory
cat: /etc/system-release-cpe: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Run you run a command like this, your *local* shell processes it, expands any globs, and produces a sequence of words that actually get executed.  That is,

1. Your local shell sees `/etc/*release*` and replaces it with the set of matching files present on your host system; then
2. It runs the expanded command `docker run ubuntu cat /etc/centos-release /etc/centos-release-upstream ...`.

You need to do two things to make this class of command work:

1. Single-quote the command, so that your local shell doesn't expand it; and
2. Explicitly cause Docker to run a shell inside the container to do the expansion there.

   ```sh
   docker run --rm ubuntu sh -c 'cat /etc/*release*'
   ```

You only need the `sh -c` wrapper if you're using things like shell globs, redirections, or trying to run multiple commands in sequence.  In a Dockerfile context, Docker will automatically add `sh -c` for you in `RUN` and `CMD` statements.